# Measuring tensor rank of the Higgs resonance

Tags: particle-physics, higgs, data-analysis

The Higgs boson is the first scalar field ever measured that is fundamental rather than composite. How do high-energy physicists determine that a given resonance in the statistics is either a scalar, vector or [fermion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermion)?

How is the rank of a field inferred from the input data obtained from the detectors? I'm assuming angular momentum plays some part, but I would like to have a better idea or overview about how they go about the calculation.

Comment: How do you know it's fundamental? I mean, we think it is in normal models, but is there experimental evidence from the announcement?

Comment: @RonMaimon, only the insight from theory, i should've mention that we *think* the Higgs is the first fundamental scalar field discovered

Answer (score 1):

This [documentary](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUBxOd8BMZw) gives a brief analysis from Christopher Pauss (CMS) and Aidan Randle (ATLAS) basically saying that the current experimental data does not exclude yet neither a scalar boson or a rank-2 boson field, although the second alternative would make this definitely not the Higgs (but something entirely different and unexpected)